# Toggle play/pause button in Next with mp3 audio

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, usesound

I'm building my website and i want a button at the bottom of my page, that will play/pause a song using useSound.
It plays when i first click, but then i can't get my song to stop.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?
Please see my code below.

```js
import useSound from 'use-sound';
import galaxySfx from '../../public/sounds/galaxy.mp3';
import styles from "./sound.module.scss";
import Aos from "aos";
import "aos/dist/aos.css";

const PlayButton = ({}) => {

  const [play, { stop, isPlaying }] = useSound(galaxySfx);

  function playSong() {
    isPlaying === true;
    play(); 
  }

  function stopSong() {
    isPlaying === false;
    stop();
  }
  
  return (
    <div className={styles.playButton}>
       <button 
        data-aos="zoom-in"
        data-aos-offset="100"
        onClick={isPlaying ? stopSong() : playSong()}
        >
         
    </button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default PlayButton;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reading the [`use-sound documentation`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/use-sound), I didn't see any `isPlaying` value from the second returned value you're destructuring.

So `isPlaying` will be undefined, but you can keep track of the playing state with a useState.

```
...

import { useState } from "react";

const PlayButton = ({}) => {
  const [isPlaying, setIsPlaying] = useState(false);
  const [play, { stop }] = useSound(galaxySfx);

  function playSong() {
    setIsPlaying(true);
    play();
  }

  function stopSong() {
    setIsPlaying(false);
    stop();
  }
```

The `onClick` prop expects a function to be called, so you shouldn't call the any of the functions you pass to it.

```
  return (
    <div className={styles.playButton}>
      <button
        data-aos="zoom-in"
        data-aos-offset="100"
        onClick={isPlaying ? stopSong : playSong}
      >
        
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It works :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the same handler for both operations. Check the state of the isPlaying variable and act accordingly:

```
function togglePlay(){
    if(isPlaying){
        stop();
    } else{
        play();
    }
}
```

Comment: `onClick={isPlaying ? stop : play}` should be enough

Comment: @Nico Seems `isPlaying` doesn't exist in the library API

Answer (score 0):

Just remove bracket, in this way functions won't run unless you **onClick**

```
onClick={isPlaying ? stop: play}
```